# Navigation Component Safe Args Issue on Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-safe-args

I have implemented **Navigation drawer** using Android N**avigation Component** which has two fragments

**1.Home Fragment**

**2.Product Fragment**

I have created another fragment **Search Fragment** as global action , which has **edit text and a button**.

**Problem :-**

From **Search Fragment** when I Click on a Button it will return to **Home Fragment with search query as safe argument**,  this is working fine but after receiving argument in Home Fragment then when I open **Product Fragment** using navigation drawer and press **back button** then the **search query** will again be sent to **Home Fragment**

**My Code :-**

**nav_graph.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
   app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
       android:name="com.example.navigation.HomeFragment"
       android:label="fragmnet_home"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragmnet_home">
         <argument
           android:name="query"
           app:argType="string"
           app:nullable="true"
           android:defaultValue="@null" />
   </fragment>

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
       android:name="com.example.navigation.SearchFragment"
       android:label="fragment_search"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" >
       <action
           android:id="@+id/action_searchFragment_to_homeFragment"
           app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
   </fragment>

   <action android:id="@+id/action_global_searchFragment" app:destination="@id/searchFragment" />
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/productFragment"
       android:name="com.example.navigation.ProductFragment"
       android:label="fragment_product"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_product" />
 </navigation>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   private lateinit var mainBinding : ActivityMainBinding
   private lateinit var mNavController : NavController
   private lateinit var appBarConfiguration: AppBarConfiguration
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       mainBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
       setContentView(mainBinding.root)

       appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
        setOf(R.id.homeFragment),
        mainBinding.drawerLayout
    )
       val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
       mNavController = navHost.findNavController()
       setSupportActionBar(mainBinding.toolbar)
       setupActionBarWithNavController(mNavController,appBarConfiguration)
       mainBinding.navView.setupWithNavController(mNavController)
   }

   override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
       return mNavController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
   }
 }
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragmnet_home) {

    private lateinit var homeBinding  : FragmnetHomeBinding
    private val arguments : HomeFragmentArgs by navArgs()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        homeBinding = FragmnetHomeBinding.bind(view)

    
        if(!arguments.query.isNullOrEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(context, "${arguments.query}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    
        homeBinding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val destination = HomeFragmentDirections.actionGlobalSearchFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(destination)
        }
    }
}
```

**SearchFragment.kt**

```
class SearchFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentSearchBinding.bind(view)
    
        binding.search.setOnClickListener {
            val query = binding.query.text.toString()
            val action = SearchFragmentDirections.actionSearchFragmentToHomeFragment(query)
            findNavController().navigate(action)

        }

    }
}
```

**ProductFragment.kt**

```
class ProductFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_product) {

    private lateinit var productBinding  : FragmentProductBinding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        productBinding = FragmentProductBinding.bind(view)
    
        productBinding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener {
            val action  = ProductFragmentDirections.actionGlobalSearchFragment()
            findNavController().navigate(action)
        }
    }
}
```

[nav_graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k3AF.png)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: That seems like the expected backstack behavior since home fragment is your start destination, could you elaborate on the expected behavior?

Comment: By default when i open home fragment it will fetch some data based on user location and when i perform search operation home fragment will show result based on search query....after i perform search and go to product fragment and click on back basically iam getting result of search query not based on user location

Comment: If you visualize the back stack as a result of your navigation it would be - Home --> Search --> Home (with Query) --> Product

So naturally back press will leave you on the previous state of Home Fragment, you could change your design and use `popUpTo` in your action for product fragment so that the stack is Home --> Search --> Product